# Change other view's background color by button state

Tags: swift

I want to change other view's background color by `UIButton` state (e.g. When button is highlighted, change background color of myView, not the button's background color). And my button is connected as `@IBOulet UIButton`.
I don't want to make another customButton class that inherits UIButton to use `isHighlighted` property. In this case, what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Swift's new framework called Combine to subscribe and listen to changes of this property. You will also need to `import Combine`.

Here is an example

```
import Combine
import UIKit

@IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    button
       .publisher(for: \.isHighlighted)
       .sink { highlighted in
          if highlighted {
             // do whatever you need here
          } 
       }
       .store(in: &subscriptions)
}
```

Here is the full [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine) from Apple if you want to use Combine

Comment: I don't use combine yet, instead I use `observe(_:options:changeHandler:)` func to solve this problem.But thank you for your answer!